# small step in understanding total turning

Tags: geometry

A quote from my lecture notes (just before defining total turning).

> Suppose $\gamma$ is a regular closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We write $T(t)$ for the
>   unit tangent. Thus $T(t) = (\cos \theta (t), \sin \theta (t))$ for
>   some $\theta (t) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone please explain why it's true that $T(t) = (\cos \theta (t), \sin \theta (t))$ for
some $\theta (t) \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an assumption missing, namely that your curve lies in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any vector, $(x,y)$, can be written in polar coordinates, with $(x,y)=r(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, with $r\geq 0$. A "unit tangent vector" is a tangent vector of unit length - that is, with $r=1$.

The fact that the $\theta$ is a continuous function of $t$ requires some proof.